# How to open Dynamically generated PDF in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

Below is my code for display pdf in the same tab itself.

.
.
.
.
.

```
tablenew.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                tablenew.AddCell(new Phrase("", time4));
                tablenew.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                tablenew.AddCell(new Phrase(total.ToString(), times1));
                pdfDoc.Add(tablenew);

                pdfDoc.Close();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;" + "filename=FeesReceiptBY" + Name + ".pdf");

                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                Response.End();
```

This snippet is working fine for display pdf in same tab. Please help me to do the same for view generated pdf in new tab. Thank you

Comment: You are showing your server-side code. You can't tell a browser to open a new tab from the server-side. You need to do this in your client-side code (in the action defined in the HTML that triggers the creation of the PDF file).

Comment: Thank you @Bruno. But pdf creation happens in server side. isn't it?

Comment: PDF creation happens on the server side, but by design, a PDF can't "command" what happens in a browser. You can't add anything to a PDF that tells the PDF to open in a new tab. The assumption you make in your question is wrong, hence your question is wrong.